# whats the most efficient way to overwrite bitmapdata

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, bitmapdata

I have a bitmapdata object that is filled with n rectangles of a width of 1 pixel and of varying heights.

I want to run through a loop and remove the old rectangle and replace it with a different one.

Should I do something like reset the each bitmap column of pixels to a background color and then add the rect i want?

```
for(i:int=0;i<bitmapdata.width;++i)

{
   (for var j:int=0;j<bitmapdata.height;j++)
{
  bitmapdata.setPixel(i,j,0x000000)
}

bitmapdata.fillrect(my new rect,0xffffff)


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I notice that you're using [`fillRect`](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#fillRect()) for something, why not use it for everything? Just `fillRect` the column in question, and then do another `fillRect` from the bottom up to make the new rectangle.

I'm not sure if that's the fastest way to do it, but you could try [`copyPixels`](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#copyPixels()), which I've heard is very fast. My suggestion for using this without any pain whatsoever is to assemble a bitmap that goes from having a column with 0px height to full height, and when you need a column of X height, copy *from* the pre-made bitmap at column X, and copy it to column Y on the original "bunch of bars" image.

Hope it helps. Post comments and I'll try to clarify in the answer, if need be.